# Heterogeneous types as values of Data.Map

Tags: haskell, dictionary

I would like to be able to do something like this, which is clearly not permitted.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
x = Map.fromList [ 
      ("Name",    ["John", "Steve", "Kelly", "Zoe"]), 
      ("Surname", ["Smith", "Lee", "Ng", "White"]), 
      ("Age",     [1, 2, 3, 4]) 
    ]
```

One possible solution is to create a type like this:

```
data L = LInt [Int] | LString [String]

x = Map.fromList [ 
      ("Name",    LString ["John", "Steve", "Kelly", "Zoe"]),
      ("Surname", LString ["Smith", "Lee", "Ng", "White"]), 
      ("Age",     LInt    [1, 2, 3, 4]) 
    ]
```

which is undesirable. Is there are a better way?

My actual use case:
 Very broadly, I am trying to implement parts of dplyr (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html), which can be viewed as a "grammar of data". Dplyr has expressions for column and row selection of tabular data as well as grouping and joining of rows, where the number of rows can be in the millions and the number of columns in the hundreds. It's not the data size that concerns me now, but the ability to produce capabilities and workflow similar to that package

Comment: It sort of looks like you’re trying to emulate extensible records. If so, I suspect you might be interested in [Vinyl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl).

Comment: Why not just define a `Person` data type: `data Person = Person { name :: String, surname :: String, age :: Int }`?  You then don't need a `Map`, just a `map`, as in `names :: [Person] -> [String]; names = map name`.

Comment: Just use a sum type for now, don't get into Vinyl if it isn't *really* necessary.

Comment: Yes, I have thought about that. It would be certainly appropriate for this case (which is a made-up example), but not very useful in general, where I'd have thousands of keys, and values that are essentially long (up to 100) tuples.

Comment: @gappy "thousands of keys" Do you mean thousands of records?  If you're calling a key the `"Name"`, `"Surname"`, or `"Age"`, then basically what you're doing is modeling a database table using `Map`, and you'd have the equivalent of thousands of columns.

Comment: Keys. The example is not my actual use case.

Comment: I can definitely provide a detailed use case. Very broadly, I am trying to implement parts of dplyr (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html), which can be viewed as a "grammar of data". Dplyr has expressions for column and row selection of tabular data as well as grouping and joining of rows, where the number of rows can be in the millions and the number of columns in the hundreds. It's not the data size that concerns me now, but the ability to produce capabilities and workflow similar to that package.

Comment: @gappy That's much clearer, thanks. I've taken the liberty of editing that comment into the text of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use existential quantification for this

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, FlexibleInstances, TypeSynonymInstances #-}

import qualified Data.Map as Map

class ColumnData c
instance ColumnData Integer
instance ColumnData String

data Column = forall c . ColumnData c => Column [c]

x = Map.fromList [
        ("Name",    Column ["John", "Steve", "Kelly", "Zoe"]),
        ("Surname", Column ["Smith", "Lee", "Ng", "White"]),
        ("Age",     Column [1::Integer, 2, 3, 4])
    ]
```

(Note we need an explicit type annotation here in the last column, because literals are overloaded, and existentials cannot quite cope with that).

Now of course the real type of the mapped data is not available from `x`. You only have `forall a . a => Column a`, and the only thing you can do with it is to call a method of `class Column`. This example defines none. You should add your own methods, which you must choose wisely.

Note, this technique is frowned upon by many hardcore haskellers, for reasons that I don't quite understand. It would be great if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: It is indeed an hot topic. In my opinion, whether existential types are a good answer strongly depends on what are the methods of class `ColumnData a`. E.g. if all you have there is `foo :: a->Int` then it's simpler to use a `[Int]` than a `Column`, and rely on laziness. In this case I believe the OP wants to fetch the strings and ints back, so we need partial or `Maybe`-returning getters, one getter for every type. If we have many types we could even turn to `Typeable`, and essentially use dynamic typing. Depending on the actual case, I might still prefer a sum type.

Comment: A relatively small, known-at-compile-time list of types sounds a lot like a sum type to me, and it can save you an awful lot of hassle. I can't see how there can be any performance benefit for Typabale over a sum type, especially if you're only tagging once per column (i.e. enforce column homogeneity in the column type). So unless you genuinely need arbitrary types, rather than just feel everything ought to be an Object, a sum type and its tags are easier.

Comment: @AndrewC The issue is not of performance, but of maintainability. To add a new tag to the sum type one needs to add it to the type definition and to every case expression with this type, recompile everything, and distribute new versions to all relevant parties. In order to add a new instance you need to change only the place where you are adding it. If the set of tags is known to be stable, the sum type is acceptable.

Comment: @chi Indeed one can implement the method dictionary as a vanilla product type. Classes and instances are just a syntatcic sugar. If you use just one method at a time, then of course it's easier to use `[Int]` or whatever. However if you have a relatively persistent collection of Columns and need to traverse it many times, applying different functions, then a dose of sugar may be in order.

Comment: Guys thanks; esp.appreciated since I am new to the language. Can you recommend some link on the subject? Even more broadly, my question to you is: am I wrong in focusing on lists (or tuples or some other type) able to contain heterogeneous types? coming from dynamic languages, this is an habit for me; but maybe it's not the Haskell way of doing things. Also, do you have links on existential quantification?